# Pass InputComboBox's KeyPress event as function parameter

Tags: delphi, events, parameters, parameter-passing, delphi-10-seattle

My OS is Windows 10 64bit, and I'm using Delphi 10.0 Seattle Update 1.

I have a function that calls an InputBox that, instead of an Edit, it contains a ComboBox. See below:

```
function funInputComboBox(const STRC_Label: String; out STRV_Result: String; const STRC_Items: String = ''; const STRC_LocateItem: String = ''): Boolean;

  function GetCharSize(Canvas: TCanvas): TPoint;
  var
    I: Integer;
    Buffer: array[0..51] of Char;
  begin
    for I := 0 to 25 do Buffer[I] := Chr(I + Ord('A'));
    for I := 0 to 25 do Buffer[I + 26] := Chr(I + Ord('a'));
    GetTextExtentPoint(Canvas.Handle, Buffer, 52, TSize(Result));
    Result.X := Result.X div 52;
  end;

var
  Form: TForm;
  Prompt: TLabel;
  Combo: TComboBox;
  DialogUnits: TPoint;
  ButtonTop, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  STRV_Result := '';

  Form := TForm.Create(Application);

  with Form do
  try
    Canvas.Font := Font;
    DialogUnits := GetCharSize(Canvas);
    BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    Caption := Application.Title;
    ClientWidth := MulDiv(180, DialogUnits.X, 4);
    Position := poScreenCenter;
    Prompt := TLabel.Create(Form);

    with Prompt do
    begin
      Parent := Form;
      Caption := STRC_Label;
      Left := MulDiv(8, DialogUnits.X, 4);
      Top := MulDiv(8, DialogUnits.Y, 8);
      Constraints.MaxWidth := MulDiv(164, DialogUnits.X, 4);
      WordWrap := True;
    end;

    Combo := TComboBox.Create(Form);

    with Combo do
    begin
      Parent := Form;
      Style := csDropDown;
      Items.Text := STRC_Items;
      ItemIndex := Items.IndexOf(STRC_LocateItem);
      Left := Prompt.Left;
      Top := Prompt.Top + Prompt.Height + 5;
      Width := MulDiv(164, DialogUnits.X, 4);
      CharCase := ecUpperCase;
      -- OnKeyPress := ?????
    end;

    ButtonTop := Combo.Top + Combo.Height + 15;
    ButtonWidth := MulDiv(50, DialogUnits.X, 4);
    ButtonHeight := MulDiv(14, DialogUnits.Y, 8);

    with TButton.Create(Form) do
    begin
      Parent := Form;
      Caption := 'OK';
      ModalResult := mrOk;
      Default := True;
      SetBounds(MulDiv(38, DialogUnits.X, 4), ButtonTop, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
    end;

    with TButton.Create(Form) do
    begin
      Parent := Form;
      Caption := 'Cancelar';
      ModalResult := mrCancel;
      Cancel := True;
      SetBounds(MulDiv(92, DialogUnits.X, 4), Combo.Top + Combo.Height + 15, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
      Form.ClientHeight := Top + Height + 13;
    end;

    Result := (ShowModal = mrOk);

    if Result then
      STRV_Result := Combo.Text;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works fine and does the job it needs to, but I want to add something else in there. Sometimes, this function will be used in places that need the text to be masked, for example, the car plates here looks like this: AAA-0000 (3 numbers and 4 letters), so, when I call this, I want to pass the procedure/function that will be called when `OnKeyPress` is triggered.

My mask validation procedure has this header:

```
procedure proValidaMascaraPlaca(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
```

It doesn't belong to any class, it's placed in your everyday `utils` unit.

When we need to use it, we do it likes this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  proValidaMascaraPlaca(Sender, Key);
end;
```

So, I want my InputComboBox to have this feature, where it could have any validation procedure we pass as a parameter:

```
with Combo do
begin
  OnKeyPress := proValidaMascaraPlaca
end;
```

Obviously, this doesn't worked, so I tried another method I saw here. It consisted of having a function that would simulate it as if it was a `procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) of object`:

```
function MakeMethod(Data, Code: Pointer): TMethod;
begin
  Result.Data := Data;
  Result.Code := Code;
end;
```

My function still doesn't have the procedure parameter, so I'm fixing the one from this example:

```
TKeyPressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) of object;

with Combo do
begin
  OnKeyPress := TKeyPressEvent(MakeMethod(@Combo, @proValidaMascaraPlaca));
end;
```

I tried `nil` instead of `@Combo`, but both failed. They did compile, but when `proValidaMascaraPlaca()` was called, it received some weird value on `Char` and `Sender`, which resulted in an Access Violation.

I hope that someone understands what I'm trying to do, or has already done/seen this, and knows what I should do to make it work. It's something I've been trying to do for some time now, that I fell like it will make me view parameters in a whole new way.

Comment: Why not making that form as a separate class (in a separate module) handling that event and populate just that function (it can be made pretty easily)?

Comment: OnKeyPress is declared as a procedure `of object`, which means it needs to be an object method. So declare a class that implements the event, assign that event to the combobox event, and call your function like you do in your TEdit sample above.

Comment: Change your  MakeMethod params to: (Sender: TObject; procAddr: pointer) then call: MakeMethod(Combo, @proValidaMascaraPlaca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type used for the `OnKeyPress` event (as with all other VCL/FMX events) is declared as `of object`, so it **requires** the assigned handler to have a `Self` parameter.  When using a class method, that parameter is implied, managed by the compiler for you.  But, when using your standalone `proValidaMascaraPlaca()` procedure with `MakeMethod()`, whatever value you assign to the `TMethod.Data` field gets passed in the `Self` parameter, but `proValidaMascaraPlaca()` has no `Self` parameter!  That is why you are getting garbage in your `Sender` and `Key` parameters, because the call stack is getting corrupted.

To make this work, you need to add an *explicit* `Self` parameter as the 1st parameter to `proValidaMascaraPlaca()`, eg:

```
procedure proValidaMascaraPlaca(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
```

`Self` will then receive whatever value you specify in the `Data` parameter of `MakeMethod()` (`@Combo` in your example), and `Sender` and `Key` will receive whatever values the `Combo` sends to them, as expected.

If you don't want to edit `proValidaMascaraPlaca()` itself (because it is in a utility library), you will have to create a separate wrapper function to pass to `MakeMethod()`, and then that wrapper can call `proValidaMascaraPlaca()` ignoring `Self`, eg:

```
procedure MyComboKeyPress(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  proValidaMascaraPlaca(Sender, Key);
end;

...

with Combo do
begin
  ...
  Combo.OnKeyPress := TKeyPressEvent(MakeMethod(nil, @MyComboKeyPress));
end;
```

A much simpler (and ultimately safer) solution would be to derive a new class from `TComboBox` instead, and override the virtual `KeyPress()` method, eg:

```
type
  TMyValidatingComboBox = class(TComboBox)
  protected
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
  end;

procedure TMyValidatingComboBox.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;
  proValidaMascaraPlaca(Self, Key);
end;

...

Combo := TMyValidatingComboBox.Create(Form);
```

Comment: This is it! Exactly what I wanted. @Victoria suggested a way that I didn't want to do, that was to transform this function in a normal form. If it was the ONLY way, then I would've done it, but this one did what I was trying to do this entire time, without the need of an actual form file. Thanks.